# What is the Rollback?

Tags: discussion, badges, rollbacks

I see that there exist the badge *cleanup*, and the description say: *first rollback* but: what is it? How can I award it?

thanks in advance

Comment: See my rollback [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/24936/revisions)

Comment: Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of [What does “First rollback” mean in the description of the Clean Up badge?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17111/what-does-first-rollback-mean-in-the-description-of-the-clean-up-badge)? And here is [another related question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/rollback-feature).

Comment: @MartinSleziak the first looks like a great target to me, the second seems outdated as the feature appears to have been modified.